# SwiftUI AVPlayer: how to hide borders on video?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avplayer

**What's the problem:** a looped video is shown with thin borders.
Interesting: there is no problem on the simulator, but on a real device it is visible. The problem disappears in the screenshot!

I tried to add a rectangle with strikeBorder above the video and change the videoGravity setting, nothing works :/

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct LoopingPlayer: UIViewRepresentable {
    let sizes = Sizes()
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        return PlayerUIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sizes.mainWidth / 1.172, height: sizes.mainWidth / 1.172))
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        //
    }
}

class PlayerUIView: UIView {
    private var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //Load Video
        let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Circle", withExtension: "mp4")!
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: fileURL)
        //Setup Player
        let player = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        //Loop
        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: playerItem)
        
        //Play video
        player.play()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder: ) has not been implemented")
    }
}

struct LoopingPlayer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoopingPlayer()
    }
}
```

**Device & simulator photos**

[image: actual device photo]
[image: simulator device]

Comment: Try setting .ignoresSafeArea() on the view and frame to full screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the Debug View Hierarchy button on the debug bar, which pauses the app in its current state, permitting the programmer to inspect and understand the UI hierarchy of any app. Its a very helpful tool during development.

[image]